# not sure what the 'if float(message) >= time.time():' does in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, time

```
import cryptocode
import time
import sys
#Function to verify that the key is valid:
def check_valid(key):
    message = cryptocode.decrypt(key, 'cryptocode is amazing')
    if message == False:
        #The key is incorrect!
        return False
    if float(message) >= time.time():
        return True
    else:
        #The key has expired!
        return False
userKeyInput = input("Please enter your product key.")
keyChecked = check_valid(userKeyInput)
if keyChecked == True:
    print("You are good to go!")
if keyChecked == False:
    print("You have either entered an invalid key or your time has expired. Sorry!")
    sys.exit()
```

###### in this code we're creating a simple "trial product key". we're letting the user use the product for 2 hours. The password we will be using is *cryptocode is amazing.*

but I'm not able to grasp the significance of this statement in this program: **if float(message) >= time.time():** , and what it is actually doing here

Comment: Please don't take the downvote barrage too hard. This place is a bit harsh before you get the "vibe". One issue with the question is that it doesn't provide necessary context (details of the key's generation), and that it isn't so much about python or programming, but about the code's logic: the "logic" tag would probably fit better, for example. Furthermore, on SO it is usually very much appreciated when you show you've done research/made your own effort prior to asking; in this case you could detail your thought process a bit more to help us understand precisely what it is that confused you.

Comment: Other possisble reasons for the downvotes: we can't know anything about the objects this code manipulates, as you didn't provide the relevant code. You should always try to provide a [mre]. Also, "please explain this very specific line of code" often can't be considered as useful for the site in general.

Comment: Well put, @ThierryLathuille: "useful for the site in general" is a very good measure of a question's quality. :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be appear to be the case that if successfully decrypted (i.e if `'cryptocode is amazing'` was the correct password), then `message` (the content of `key` once decrypted) contains the time of expiration in float format. Hence, the line you're asking about converts it into float and compares it with the current time to check if it had already expired. (If the current time > expiration time, then the expiration time is in the past: the key had, indeed, already expired.)

In other words: there's an implicit assumption here that the key given to the user was the expiration time, encrypted.